# Duplicated rows when merging dataframes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I am currently merging two dataframes with an inner join. However, after merging, I see all the rows are duplicated even when the columns that I merged upon contain the same values.

Specifically, I have the following code.

```py
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['email_address'], how='inner')
```

Here are the two dataframes and the results.

`df1`

```
          email_address    name   surname
0  john.smith@email.com    john     smith
1  john.smith@email.com    john     smith
2       elvis@email.com   elvis   presley
```

`df2`

```
          email_address    street  city
0  john.smith@email.com   street1    NY
1  john.smith@email.com   street1    NY
2       elvis@email.com   street2    LA
```

`merged_df`

```
          email_address    name   surname    street  city
0  john.smith@email.com    john     smith   street1    NY
1  john.smith@email.com    john     smith   street1    NY
2  john.smith@email.com    john     smith   street1    NY
3  john.smith@email.com    john     smith   street1    NY
4       elvis@email.com   elvis   presley   street2    LA
5       elvis@email.com   elvis   presley   street2    LA
```

My question is, shouldn't it be like this?

This is how I would like my `merged_df` to be like.

```
          email_address    name   surname    street  city
0  john.smith@email.com    john     smith   street1    NY
1  john.smith@email.com    john     smith   street1    NY
2       elvis@email.com   elvis   presley   street2    LA
```

Are there any ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
list_2_nodups = list_2.drop_duplicates()
pd.merge(list_1 , list_2_nodups , on=['email_address'])
```

### [image]

The duplicate rows are expected.  Each john smith in `list_1` matches with each john smith in `list_2`.  I had to drop the duplicates in one of the lists.  I chose `list_2`.

Answer (score 11):

DO NOT drop duplicates BEFORE the merge, but after!

Best solution is do the merge and then drop the duplicates.

In your case:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['email_address'], how='inner')
merged_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['email_address'], keep='first', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Why do we need to drop the duplicates after the merge? and why does the merge generate duplciates? Could you help me to understand? Many thanks.

Comment: @user19562955 Merge is a mathematical operation on sets and it works the same way. When you have more than one match of a value in the second set, it puts it in the final dataframe. In the example above, given that the key was "email_address", the question is: does the email in the first line of df1 have a correspondent in any line of df2? Yes (all matching lines are added). And so on. In practice this happens very often and the best way to keep only distinct records is to handle the duplicates after the merge.

Comment: this solution created an empty data frame for me

Comment: @coding_is_fun use print function after the merge and see if the data frame is empty. The method drop_duplicates would not make an empty data frame. Something wrong with your merge operation is more probably.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure you don't have duplicates in your keys, you can use the `validate` parameter:

> **validate : str, optional**
>
> If specified, checks if merge is of specified
> type.
>
> - “one_to_one” or “1:1”: check if merge keys are unique in both
>   left and right datasets.
> - “one_to_many” or “1:m”: check if merge keys
>   are unique in left dataset.
> - “many_to_one” or “m:1”: check if merge
>   keys are unique in right dataset.
> - “many_to_many” or “m:m”: allowed,
>   but does not result in checks.

In your case, you don't want any duplicate keys in the "right" dataframe `df2`, so you need to set `validate` to `many_to_one`.

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['email_address'], validate='many_to_one')
```

If you have duplicate keys in `df2`, the function will return this error:

```
MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in right record; not a many-to-one merge
```

To drop duplicate keys in `df2` and do a merge you can use:

```
keys = ['email_address']
df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=keys), on=keys)
```

Make sure you set the subset parameter in `drop_duplicates` to the key columns you are using to merge. If you don't specify a subset `drop_duplicates` will compare all columns and if some of them have different values it will not drop those rows.