# Pandas merge creates duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a merge of two dataframes, but when I do so, I have many duplicates entries.
My code is a little bit long, so here are the example of two datasets :

```
 df1
        Season  SeasonType  ... PitchingWalksPerNineInnings_17 PitchingWeightedOnBasePercentage_17
GameID                      ...
47547   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
47546   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
50022   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
47556   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
47557   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
...        ...         ...  ...                            ...                                 ...
49970   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
49964   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
49974   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
49975   2017.0         1.0  ...                            NaN                                 NaN
47562      NaN         NaN  ...                            NaN                                 NaN

df2
   GameID  StatID_28  ...  PitchingWalksPerNineInnings_28  PitchingWeightedOnBasePercentage_28
0   47562    1748078  ...                             5.0                                0.351

[1 rows x 52 columns]
```

GameID column is my index on both.
df1 can have multiple columns similar with df2, that's why I'm using this to get them :

```
columnsMerge = list(set(df.columns).intersection(set(tpstatdf.columns)))
columnsMerge.append('GameID')
```

I've shared the csv file generated here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RVKNsB42ixQ2I2WUqqu_dDNjmcVIz5No?usp=sharing

Please find below what I got. What is expected is to have only one line with the game id, agregated with the following two.

[image]

Any help will be very appreciated on that.

Thanks

Geoffrey

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019591/duplicated-rows-when-merging-dataframes-in-python

Comment: nope, the drop duplicate do not work. And actually, only one column is duplicated. A better function will be something like fuse, based on the gameid column

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all columns, you can `join` them with a suffix, and keep only the cols which are in columnsMerge.

```
df_merged = df1.join(df2, how='right', rsuffix='_df2')
columnsMerge = list(set(df.columns).intersection(set(tpstatdf.columns)))
cols = [c if any(c in s for s incolumnsMerge) for c in df_merged.columns]
df_merged = df_merged[cols]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Actually df1 and df2 do have the same columns, but don't have the same value, except the GameID, which is the one I'm using the merge (this is my index on both df)

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope I got you right this time.

Comment: almost. Let's say for example I have df1 with the following columns / values:
`GameID - X - X1 - X2 - X3`
And I have df2 :
`GameID - X20 - X21 - X22`

Expected result will be :
`GameID - X1 - X2 - X3 - X20 - X21 - X22`

With the values of both df - and merge done with the gameID as it's a common value